# update component when updating a resource

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I created a simple todo app and when deleting an item from my vuex store the component rendering the todo list updates automatically. When updating a todo item from "pending" to "completed" the component doesn't update automatically. The store gets updated but I think there is no trigger that says

> hey, a resource from an array got updated, please render again

How can I force it to do so?

I created a small example showing what I mean, if you delete a todo item the component will update. If you click on a "update" button it will not change.

https://codesandbox.io/s/x3wv1yp33w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a reactivity problem:

> Vue does not allow dynamically adding new root-level reactive
> properties to an already created instance. However, it’s possible to
> add reactive properties to a nested object using the Vue.set(object,
> key, value) method ([source](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats))

In your store's `UPDATE_TODO` mutation, change this line:

```js
state.todos[todoIndex] = updatedTodo
```

to this:

```js
Vue.set(state.todos, todoIndex, updatedTodo)
```

and of course, add `import Vue from 'vue'` at the top of the file.
It should work this way.